# python--pytractor 'WebDriverMixin' object has no attribute 'set_script_timeout'?

Tags: python-2.7

from pytractor.mixins import WebDriverMixin
p=webDriverMixin()
Except:
AttributeError: 'WebDriverMixin' object has no attribute 'set_script_timeout' when I execute the script

Answer (score 0):

You have to import webdriver not WebDriverMixin

```
In [7]: from pytractor import webdriver

In [8]: driver = webdriver.Firefox()

In [9]: driver.set_script_timeout(10)

In [10]:
```